# Right Clicking on JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, right-click, mouselistener

trying to add a mouseAdapter to a JButton for a right click to flag the cell.  Problem is when I instantiate it onto the button, it won't let me.  Maybe because it already has an actionlistener on it?  I'm not too sure.  Any help is appreciated.  I'm creating a Minesweeper game, fyi.

```
button = new JButton[size][size];
ButtonListener bl = new ButtonListener();
for (int r = 0; r < size; r++) {
for (int c = 0; c < size; c++) {
button[r][c] = new JButton("");
button[r][c].addActionListener(bl);
button[r][c].addMouseListener (new MouseAdapter());``
// error message: cannot instantiate the type MouseAdapter
panel.add(button[r][c]);
```

eventually if that works, I want to incorporate this into the game:

```
button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { 
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getButton() == 3) { // if right click
            button.setText("F");
            button.getModel().setPressed(false);
            // button.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            button.setText("X");
            button.getModel().setPressed(true);
            // button.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @deporter What are you talking about ? This is the guy's first question...

Comment: the compiler is your friend here: why would you ever want to register a do-nothing-mouseListener :-)

Answer (score 5):

For Minesweeper game you have look for

1) `JToggleButton`

2) add `Icon` to `JToggleButton` methods

- `JToggleButton#setIcon();`
- `JToggleButton#setSelectedIcon();`
- `JToggleButton#setDisabledIcon();`

3) add `MouseListener` to `JToggleButton`

4) override `mouseClicked` with method `SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton()` inside

result could be

[image][image][image]

from code

```
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class MyToggleButton extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Icon errorIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon");
    private Icon infoIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon");
    private Icon warnIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.warningIcon");

    public MyToggleButton() {
        final JToggleButton toggleButton = new JToggleButton();
        toggleButton.setBorderPainted(false);
        toggleButton.setBorder(null);
        toggleButton.setFocusable(false);
        toggleButton.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
        toggleButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        toggleButton.setIcon((errorIcon));
        toggleButton.setSelectedIcon(infoIcon);
        //toggleButton.setRolloverIcon((infoIcon));
        //toggleButton.setPressedIcon(warnIcon);
        toggleButton.setDisabledIcon(warnIcon);
        toggleButton.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e) && e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                    if (toggleButton.isEnabled()) {
                        toggleButton.setEnabled(false);
                    } else {
                        toggleButton.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                }
            }

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            }
        });
        add(toggleButton);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyToggleButton t = new MyToggleButton();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

MouseAdapter is an abstract class and you cannot create instances of it.
That is why you get the error.

```
button[r][c].addMouseListener (new MouseAdapter());  //  this will not work

button[r][c].addMouseListener (new MouseAdapter(){});  // this will
                                                 ^

button[r][c].addMouseListener (new MouseAdapter(){
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
         // and this will actually do sth. ; )
    }
});
```