# How to color Jbutton in java

Tags: java, swing, colors, jbutton, jtogglebutton

hello guys i have problem coloring those buttons  the background allways change color but the other stay in grey color, any way to change that to other color? /sorry for my english/

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Prepinac extends JFrame        
{                          
JToggleButton prepinac1 = new JToggleButton("prepinac");    
 public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Prepinac prepinace = new Prepinac();        
    Container kontainer = prepinace.getContentPane(); 
    kontainer.setLayout(new FlowLayout());   
    kontainer.add(prepinace.prepinac1);           
    kontainer.add(new JButton("tlacidlo"));

    prepinace.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);         
    prepinace.pack();                                           
    prepinace.setVisible(true);                              
} 
}
```

Comment: See this,,,
http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=180578

Answer (score 3):

Basically, there are these four ways:

- [`JToggleButton#setBackground`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBackground%28java.awt.Color%29)
- nicer than `setBackground`, [`JToggleButton#setSelectedIcon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setSelectedIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29), maybe this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9369476/714968)
- or put them  together `setBackground` && `setSelectedIcon`
- best of all is to use [Custom Look and Feel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954616/look-and-feel-in-java), some of them implment this features by default

Answer (score 2):

You could try using nimbus L&F, and then set the base color of the layout

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
UIManager.put("base", new java.awt.Color(80,0,0));
```