# How to find if image is clicked in JApplet?

Tags: java, swing, applet, japplet

It is to support image dragging.  How to find if an image is clicked in `JApplet`?

I'm sure there is an easy way to do this, but I've looked everywhere and cannot seem to find it.

Comment: Hopefully this thread can help you in finding, [How to get Mouse Clicks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10345165/1057230) on `Image`

Answer (score 4):

Options:

- Use a JLabel to hold the image, and give it a MouseListener. Simple.
- Or create a JButtton and use the Image as the button's ImageIcon. Probably simpler.

Comment: It needs to be dragged... probably should have mentioned that

Comment: @RyleyMatos: then you'll probably want to go the JLabel/MouseAdapter route. Also, please let's try to avoid the changing requirements game here as it can get very frustrating.

Comment: How do I change paint the label to the JApplet with x y coordinates?

Comment: @RyleyMatos: give the container that holds the JLabel a null layout, and then set the JLabel's location via its `setLocation(int x, int y)` method. Then call `repaint()` on the container.

Answer (score 4):

See the [Drag and Drop and Data Transfer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html) lesson of the tutorial.

If the purpose of the dragging is to change the order in a slideshow or similar, look to a [`JList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html).  See [`setDragEnabled(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setDragEnabled%28boolean%29) & [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more details.

For the display component, I would recommend a `JLabel` as suggested by @Hover.  `JList` uses a `JLabel` as the rendering component by default.