# How to add JLabel to Japplet with set x,y coordinates

Tags: java, jlabel, japplet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find if image is clicked in JApplet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543745/how-to-find-if-image-is-clicked-in-japplet)

Im figuring out the easiest way to do my game, and I think thats using a label with a mouse listener. The problem is I don't know how to add it to the applet with set, adjustable coordinates. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: *"figuring out the easiest way to do my game"*  If you expect us to give you the best advice, you might think about giving us more detail about the game.

Comment: He already has an active question on this same subject.

Answer (score 1):

Just use absolute positioning. By not using a layout manager you can place components in a panel or frame with the setLocation method.

```
component.setLocation(x,y);
```

Addendum: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html