# Self created JToggleButton: change icons

Tags: java, swing, icons, jtogglebutton

I have written a class that extends JToggleButton.

Everything works fine, except that I can't change the icons of the button.

Here is my code of the class:

```
package be.blauweregen.lichtsturing;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class MyToggleButton extends JToggleButton {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String s;

    public MyToggleButton(String str) {
        super(str);
        s = str;
    }

    public MyToggleButton(String str, Boolean sel) {
        super(str, sel);
        s = str;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (this.isSelected() && this.isEnabled()) { // manueel en aan
            int w = getWidth();
            int h = getHeight();
            g.setColor(Color.green); // selected color
            g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
            g.setColor(Color.black); // selected foreground color
            g.drawString(s, (w - g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(s)) / 2 + 1,
                    (h + g.getFontMetrics().getAscent()) / 2 - 1);
            setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
        } else if (this.isSelected() && !this.isEnabled()) { // automatisch en
                                                                // aan
            int w = getWidth();
            int h = getHeight();

            g.setColor(Color.green); // selected color
            g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
            g.setColor(Color.black); // selected foreground color
            g.drawString(s, (w - g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(s)) / 2 + 1,
                    (h + g.getFontMetrics().getAscent()) / 2 - 1);
            setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        } else if (!this.isSelected() && this.isEnabled()) { // manueel en uit
            int w = getWidth();
            int h = getHeight();
            g.setColor(Color.red); // selected color
            g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
            g.setColor(Color.black); // selected foreground color
            g.drawString(s, (w - g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(s)) / 2 + 1,
                    (h + g.getFontMetrics().getAscent()) / 2 - 1);
            setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
        } else if (!this.isSelected() && !this.isEnabled()) { // automatisch en
                                                                // uit
            int w = getWidth();
            int h = getHeight();
            g.setColor(Color.red); // selected color
            g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
            g.setColor(Color.black); // selected foreground color
            g.drawString(s, (w - g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(s)) / 2 + 1,
                    (h + g.getFontMetrics().getAscent()) / 2 - 1);
            setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        }

    }
}
```

I use the code in this way in my program:

```
btnGangSanitair = new MyToggleButton("Gang sanitair");
btnGangSanitair.setSelectedIcon(new ImageIcon("Z:\\Development\\Java\\BlauweRegen\\famfamfam_silk_icons_v013\\icons\\application_edit.png"));
btnGangSanitair.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Client.class.getResource("/be.blauweregen.icons/arrow_refresh.png")));
```

What am I doing wrong?

The icons don't appear in the program.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't recreate and reload `ImageIcon`s on runtime, load all `ImageIcon`s as local variables once and only one time,
2. Use `setBackground()` instead of `paintComponent()`
3. Use [proper setXxxIcon methods for JToggleButton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9369476/714968)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to mKorbel's comments, all your wonderful custom painting is over painting what the super call did, thus painting over your icon

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Was just typing that I had used that approach.. You were 10 seconds too fast. Thank you for the answer.