# Right click setIcon() to mark bomb - Minesweeper

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener, minesweeper, jtogglebutton

I am pretty new to programming and am trying to make a Minesweeper GUI. The game worked perfectly right clicking a JToggleButton displayed a "B" for bomb on the button, but when I replaced the setText() with setIcon() in the mouselistener it shows the icon when both left and right clicking occurs. I didn't have this problem when setText().

```
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        if(e.isMetaDown())
            if(btnPresses == 0)
            {
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                btnPresses++;
            }
            //if(btn[y][x].getText().equals("B"))
            if(btn[y][x].getIcon()==flag)
            {
                //btn[y][x].setText("");
                btn[y][x].setIcon(null);
                if(bombs[y][x]!=BOMB)
                    markers++;
            }
            else
            {
                //btn[y][x].setText("B");
                btn[y][x].setIcon(flag);
                if(bombs[y][x]==BOMB)
                    markers++;
                else
                    markers--;
            }
```

I added a btn[y][x].setIcon(null) to the actionlistener, which causes the flag icon to appear only briefly when left clicking but I'd rather it not appear at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to distinguish between a left mouse button click, MouseEvent.BUTTON3, and a right mouse button click, MouseEvent.BUTTON3, and then act accordingly. For example, when I did something like this, I set the "flag" boolean in my model (using MVC) via:

```
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
   if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
      model.upDateButtonFlag();
   }
}
```

The MouseListener should be used only to set or unset the flag. Otherwise you should have your JButton respond via its ActionListener for left button clicks.

Comment: OMG! I forgot the braces under the "if(e.isMetaDown)"

Comment: @AH: yes, *all* blocks should be enclosed in curly braces, even one line blocks. Make this a habit now.

Comment: +1 example by using [SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9369476/714968)

Comment: Good catch! Many IDEs can highlight such vagaries

Answer (score 0):

Add a `System.err.println("" + System.currentTimeMillis() + " " + e);` to the beginning of your handler. I strongly suspect your code is being called more times than you think - as a single click can generate multiple events. Once you know what is going on, it should be easy to fix.

Comment: Tried this line and it is outputting only one event per click. Output: "1342746827280 java.awt.event.MouseEvent[MOUSE_PRESSED,(40,17),absolute(295,191),button=1,modifiers=Button1,extModifiers=Button1,clickCount=1] on javax.swing.JToggleButton..."